# Why is my "flair" Identicon different from my standard Identicon?

Tags: discussion, bug

I was poking around the newly designed Network Profile page, and clicked on the "Flair" tab.  The [Identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) embedded in the flair isn't the standard Identicon for my account, which is shared across each stack that I've joined.

Here's a big screenshot (click to zoom). The flair is in the lower-left corner.

[image]

I believe they used to be the same.  What's up?

Comment: Weird. I'll ask around, but no guarantees over a weekend.

Comment: @W5VO. No problem, no rush. I don't even use the flair :)  Have a good weekend!

Comment: I think you meant the other right.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, @Olin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue currently being addressed on meta site-wide. [Why is there a peeking duck in my profile pic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic) or [Moderator election ballot: Different default images for candidates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283642/moderator-election-ballot-different-default-images-for-candidates) or [Why is my profile image different?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different/283656#283656)

You could upload a new avatar to fix it, or just wait till it's resolved site wide.

Comment: Thanks, Passerby :)

Answer (score -1):

Each SE can, to a degree, display different information that the user deems useful for that SE. How then to decide which Identicon, which is different for each SE, to use for the flair?

See the "update profile info" below your synopsys. Click it & choose which SE you want to essentially be your "base profile"  the Identicon will be copied from that one